# GIF and APNG images in IE

Tags: html, image, gif

I have an animated GIF image. I will be placing it in a transparent overlay in my html page. Is there any way to Smoothen the image (the edges are quite rough, they look fine in the psd)
and is there ANY way to load an APNG in IE 6,7,8.

Comment: you can see here which browsers support APNG's http://caniuse.com/apng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG), it is not possible to use APNG in Internet Explorer.

Your only chance of a workaround is to create the GIF (which doesn't support alpha transparency like PNG does, which is the reason for the rough edges) in a way that works with the background you're putting it on  - like, defining the dominant background colour as the transparent colour so the edges are calculated for that colour instead of black.

It will depend on the image editing program you are using whether that is possible or not.

Comment: Yeah i read that up. I was wondering if there were any workarounds.

Comment: @zIndex there seems to be one: http://ajaxian.com/archives/apng-class-get-apng-going-on-all-browsers can't speak to its usefulness but might be for you

Comment: ahh, thanks. But thats for firefox and Opera only. I can get the APNG running flawlessly in firefox :) IE is the obstinate one.

Comment: @zIndex no, as far as I can see, this is supposed to fix it for IE. Native functionality will be used in FF and Opera. The demo site seems down but the package can be downloaded: http://mootools.net/forge/p/apng

Comment: Yes i seem to have run into the same problem now. I will post my results once it try out asap.

Comment: @Pekka, Its does not seem to be working in IE. If u have made any progress i'd love to have a look at your script. And as for your GIF image theory, i fine tuned the image upto pixel level with the dominant BG and now the edges are quite smooth.

Comment: @zIndex ah, that's too bad! Odd, it does promise full compatibility. The fine tuned version is probably the best way to go if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but for those that want to support APNG on IE or Safari, there is a javascript workaround that's found below:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/apng-class-get-apng-going-on-all-browsers
http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/apng/

Currently, I believe FF (not sure the version) and Opera (not sure of the version) support it at the browser level. For Chrome, you can download the APNG extension to get it to work.

Hope this helps.